# Activity Databinding in wf 4.0

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-activity

i want to display some datatypes in a combobox. the datatypes are wrapped in the following class:

```
public class TDataTypeBinder: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name ;
        }
        set
        {
            name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    private DataType datatype;
    public DataType Datatype
    {
        get
        {
            return datatype;
        }
        set
        {
            datatype = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Datatype");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="TDataTypeBinder"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="valueToSelect">The value to select.</param>
    public TDataTypeBinder(string valueToSelect)
    {
        Name = valueToSelect;
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler eh = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (null != eh)
        {
            eh(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
    }

}
```

currently i have a property for the binding:

```
public CollectionView DatatypesDisplayed
    {
        get
        {

            List<TDataTypeBinder> list = new List<TDataTypeBinder>();
            list.Add(new TDataTypeBinder("String"));
            list.Add(new TDataTypeBinder("Float"));
            list.Add(new TDataTypeBinder("Integer"));

            myDatatypes = new CollectionView(list);
            return myDatatypes;
        }
    }
```

which is connected via xaml in the WorkflowElement:

```
<... WorkflowViewElement ...
<ComboBox Name="gType" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ModelItem.DatatypesDisplayed }" DisplayMemberPath="Name" Margin="3" MinWidth="150" Height="20" />
```

I dont get anything in my combobox `gType`. What did i wrong? I am new to WPF and Workflow 4.0 so i think this isnt a hard one for you.

Thanks in advice,
el

Answer (score 0):

If your DatatypesDisplayed collection is null when the UI initially binds to it, then subsequent changes will not be notified to the View... are you initialising the `CollectionView` in your class' constructor?

Also - double check that you're setting the View's `DataContext` to be an instance of your class...

Cheers, Ian

EDIT:

OK - so have a look at this line in the xaml that's defining your combobox:

```
<ComboBox Name="gType" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ModelItem.DatatypesDisplayed }" DisplayMemberPath="Name" Margin="3" MinWidth="150" Height="20" />
```

this means that the 'stuff' that should appear in your combo box should live in a collection called DataTypesDisplayed. This can be a collection of any kind of objects, as long as that object exposes a property called 'Name', because we are using this for the DisplayMemberPath. Furthermore, this collection should be a property of something called ModelItem, and ModelItem should be a property of whatever it is that is the DataContext for your view...

put it all together, and I would expect to see something like this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // Set the View's DataContext to be an instance of the class that contains your CollectionView...
        this.DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
    }
}


public class MainWindowViewModel
{
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
    }

    public object ModelItem { get; set; }
}

public class ModelItem
{
    public CollectionView DataTypesDisplayed { get; set; }
}
```

I'm not too sure *why* you have the ModelItem in the Path of your ItemsSource Binding, and you may find that you don't need it - just place the CollectionView directly in the ViewModel...

Comment: Thank you for your awnser. My CollectionView is not null initialy. Do i have to set a DataContext when i have defined my designer in WF? How can i set a DataContext?